# Is it possible to have custom JSON serialzier specific to endpoint?

Tags: java, spring, quarkus

I would like to output the very same class with different set of fields in different endpoints.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that with Jackson's `@JsonView` support in RESTEasy Reactive.

See [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#jsonview-support) for more details.

For even more advanced customization, you can use `@CustomSerialization`, as mentioned [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#completely-customized-per-method-serialization).

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can output string. You will have full control over serialization that way.

Comment: Yes, but how to generate that string? It should be a representation of nested objects serializations as needed.